# MongoDB on Android

Tags: android, mongodb

Does anyone know how does MondgoDB works on Android. 
Does it work locally and you the data gets replicated later? 
 Does work only online with just a web backend?

Comment: We've been looking for something similar and the closest thing we've found is http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/couchbase-mobile

Comment: Almost all the answers are dated, please look into this https://realm.io/docs/java/latest

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'm going to revive this thread and say that MongoDB's Java driver IS currently compatible with Android. Some novice developers might have trouble getting their apps to use MongoDB's java library, so I'll just outline what you have to do (though all of this could be obsolete by the time you're reading this).

Go to your app build.gradle file. Add this "compile" entry under your dependencies (you will probably have to replace the version):

```
dependencies {
  ...
  implementation 'org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:3.0.3'
}
```

As you can see, the driver's version as of this post is 3.0.3. You can find the current version by searching "mongo-java-driver" or any related terms at http://search.maven.org.

If you're connecting to an external database, you will of course need to add the INTERNET permission to your manifest. Connecting to one is pretty simple. Here's an example. Replace the username, password, host domain, port, and database name:

```
MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI( "mongodb://username:password@www.example.com:12345/db-name" );
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
```

Since this is network related, you will need to run all of that in an AsyncTask class.

Following the java tutorials on https://www.mongodb.org/ should be relatively straightforward from here on out.

Comment: This might repeat the scenario which happened when apache lib was used to do http communications where Android had more optimized versions. People faced problems when android depricated support to it.

Comment: Connecting to mongodb directly from an android app has several drawbacks and should be avoided if possible. From the security perspective server location and credentials al available to anyone who can de-compile your application. From the operations perspective it becomes hard or impossible to manage de connection pools and various performance or scalability issues may arise.

Comment: Irony is that dear @Astral1990 you look novice here, you are talking about mongo client and here we are looking for a local mongodb object/document storage solution.

Comment: The above workaround is not clear, can you please make it clear

Answer (score 55):

MongoDB has downloads for several [operating systems](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads). However, Android is not one of those systems.

People use MongoDB as a "web service" for storing data, but it does not have any features to support multi-master replication or your occasionally connected mobile scenario.

If you need these types of features, you'll want to check out [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) which specifically targets this scenario with [Android Couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase).

Comment: This question was answered in Jul 2011. How does the state of things look now in Jun 2013 ?

Comment: The Downloads page for MongoDB still lists the same support. And frankly, MongoDB is really _not_ designed for devices like Android. The way it maps data into memory is not a really good idea for small devices with limited RAM.

The Android Couchbase project seems to have been abandoned and replaced with a "Lite" version: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-lite-android

Comment: Also checkout PouchDB. It is a couchdb implementation that uses the browser's db for storage. Works on Android: http://pouchdb.com/

Comment: The mongo-java-driver will now work on Android to connect to a web server with MongoDB.

Answer (score 3):

[**Dory mongoDB Server**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=io.tempage.dorymongo)

Great new Android application 
**No Need to root your Phone and You Can Run your js File From anywere.**

*MongoDB (from humongous) is a free and open-source cross-platform document-oriented database program. Classified as a NoSQL database program, MongoDB uses JSON-like documents with schemas.*

**Usage:**
1: install Dory mongoDB Server
2: run your Server
3: install Dory node.js
4: run this code in your js file:

**Code:**

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test', { useMongoClient: true });
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

var Cat = mongoose.model('Cat', { name: String });

var kitty = new Cat({ name: 'Zildjian' });
kitty.save(function (err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  } else {
    console.log('meow');
  }
});
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Thanks. Even the google search did not find this app

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately Mongo Java Driver 3.8.0 is not compatible with Android anymore: https://gitlab.com/mvysny/umn/issues/1 and they don't even claim Android support. Maybe following the unofficial fork or trying GnuSasl could help? [mongodb 3.x driver Android compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529484/mongodb-3-x-driver-android-compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

**MongoDB is also available for android** 
The only problem is that it does not have well-structured documentation for android..

I recently managed to connect my android application to the remote database

here is a sample unit application
https://github.com/i-sachinkumar/MongoDB-for-Android

*Its readme file contains all the steps to be followed in the back-end as well as in the android studio*

Answer (score 0):

Reactivating this Topic again after 2 years.

I was looking for an android app exactly like MongoDB Compass, but couldn't find "exactly" like it. So deciding to make one (and open source it)

Based on links given in @Astral1990's answer, I found [this](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/tree/master).

Now for a gist:

Gradle file: (more info [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/getting-started/installation/))

```
implementation 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-sync:4.2.3'
```

For creating the client: (more info [here](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/authentication/))

```
MongoClient mongoClient = MongoClients.create("mongodb://user1:pwd1@host1/?authSource=db1");
```

Then other things:

```
// get db
MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
// get collection in db
MongoCollection<Document> coll = database.getCollection("myTestCollection");
// list collections (permission has to be present)
for (String name : database.listCollectionNames()) {
    System.out.println(name);
}
```

[Queries and others](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/driver/tutorials/perform-read-operations/)

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to install MongoDB in android devices because the MongoDB's latest releases doesn't support android device's CPU architecture.

But I read an article on codipher.com and i gave it a try and it finally worked, i was able to use MongoDB on my android phone.

Here is the link: https://codipher.com/install-mongodb-on-android/