# Android + NoSQL

Tags: android, mongodb, couchdb, database, nosql

I am developing an app which is supposed to send data to a MySQL DB in a remote server so as to be later displayed in a webpage that grabs the data from that server, and I was wondering if it's possible to use some NoSQL solution instead of MySQL?

I have been reading about CouchDB and MongoDB but I still don't understand if I could use them for my purposes, as for example with MongoDB, I have to install the app on the Android phone and I still have no clue how I can install it in a remote server.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MongoDB on Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887887/mongodb-on-android)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CouchBase Mobile](http://www.couchbase.com/products-and-services/couchbase-mobile) is probably what you are looking for. I don't think there is an equivalent solution for MongoDB yet, and it's not really what it is designed for anyway.

EDIT: But what is wrong with the MySQL option?

Comment: do you know if is it possible to install it in the Android emulator

Comment: Haven't really looked into it, but the [Couchbase Mobile for Android](http://www.couchbase.org/get/couchbase-mobile-for-android) page should answer your questions. They have a video tutorial to get your started.

Comment: uh great, I didn't see neither of those pages.. thanks a lot!

Comment: does android inbuilt Sqlite has any option of this kind? remote synch?

Comment: @Vache there is nothing wrong, but I was just wondering if it would be better for my case: I want a bunch of Android phones to send data to a remote MySQL server through PHP, and I was wondering if it would be easier/more efficient to use CouchDB for this.

Answer (score 2):

iBoxDB for Java can install in the Android emulator,hava an interface called 'IBoxRecycler' , it can collect database's data(byte[]) , then convert data to sql, and replicate to server. if server also iBoxDB, just send data don't need convert

```
for (OPEntity k : BoxData.getActions()) {
  String tableName = k.TableName;
  Map<String, Object> v = k.Select();
  String sql = ( tableName, v ) to SQL;
  SendToMySQL( sql );
}
```

https://github.com/iboxdb/forjava

Answer (score 0):

A new kid on the block is [JasDB](https://github.com/oberasoftware/jasdb/wiki). It has an exceedingly simple API and [works on Android](https://github.com/oberasoftware/jasdb/wiki/Using-JasDB-on-Android-devices). Examples:

#### create object

```
SimpleEntity entity = new SimpleEntity();
entity.addProperty("title", "Title of my content");
entity.addProperty("text", "Some big piece of text content");
bag.addEntity(entity);
```

#### range query

```
QueryExecutor executor = bag.find(QueryBuilder.createBuilder().field("age")
   .greaterThan(10).field("age").smallerThan(30).sortBy("country"));
```

Answer (score 0):

There is also

https://github.com/neo-expert/thingdb

It is very lightweight (~50 KB)
The API is MongoDB-like:

```
DB db = new DB("./db");
Doc doc=new Doc();
doc.put("name","test");
doc.put("age",31);
db.insert(doc);
//later you can get the saved doc:
Doc d=db.findOne(eq("name","test"));
```

You can also create Indexes:

```
db.createIndex("fieldname");
```