# MongoDB or Google Mobile Backend Starter for Android?

Tags: android, mongodb, cloud, google-cloud-storage, database

I am developing an android app (prediction app) which requires to store

(a) prediction result and 
(b) actual user result.

Based on this data, I want users to show actual predicted/actual result values to user.
So this requires very small amount of data to be stored and and shared via a common database in cloud.

Currently I was going through [Google Cloud Platform: Mobile Backend Starter](https://developers.google.com/cloud/samples/mbs/), which i thought is a very nice option. But looking into the sample, it seems it requires  minimum API level of 15. But I want to support my app from API level 8 and above, i.e. android 2.2 Can it be used for API level 8 and above?

Can MongoDB work with android ?  [This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887887/mongodb-on-android) says, it is not available for Android. is it so?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: Updated the question. Please reconsider before closing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested parse.com a few times and it works for smaller projects for free.