# Can i use MongoDB as localstorage?

Tags: android, mongodb, hybrid-mobile-app

How can i use MongoDB as local storage for android app in Hybrid App Development ?
can i use a mongodb as my local storage for my android app

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use MongoDB on Android. Maybe you should take a look at CouchDB/Couchbase-lite-android as proposed in the answer to this question: [MongoDB on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887887/mongodb-on-android)