# mongodb 3.x driver Android compatibility

Tags: android, mongodb, mongodb-java

I'm developing an Android app that use the java mongodb driver 3.0.3 to connect to every instance of mongodb.

The connector code to a generic istance is:

```
try{
    MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, dbname, pass.toCharArray());
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient( new ServerAddress(server , port ), Arrays.asList(credential));
    MongoDatabase db = mongoClient.getDatabase(dbname);
    System.out.println("Connect to database successfully ");
    Iterator i= mongoClient.listDatabaseNames().iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()){
        Log.d("DATABASE", (String) i.next());
    }
    Iterator ic= db.listCollectionNames().iterator();
    while (ic.hasNext()){
        Log.d("COLLECTION", (String) ic.next());
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
}
```

At runtime I have some error:

> 09-11 19:13:50.898    7418-7418/it.mysite.mongodbviewer W/org.bson.ObjectId﹕ Failed to get process identifier from JMX, using random number instead java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;

and

> com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient

that generate a loop with this:

> I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class

Anyone has a solution?
java/lang/management/ManagementFactory seems not to exist for Android, how can you solve? If this is the center of the problem.

Thanks in advance, Matteo

PS: The complete log is:

```
09-11 19:13:50.898    7418-7418/it.mysite.mongodbviewer W/org.bson.ObjectId﹕ Failed to get process identifier from JMX, using random number instead
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
at org.bson.types.ObjectId.createProcessIdentifier(ObjectId.java:502)
at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:460)
at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterId.<init>(ClusterId.java:47)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:40)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:660)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:646)
at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:275)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:184)
at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:160)
at it.mysite.mongodbmanager.data.MongoDBDriver.connect(MongoDBDriver.java:102)
at it.mysite.mongodbmanager.fragments.MongoDBAccountDetailFragment.onClick(MongoDBAccountDetailFragment.java:101)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19865)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/it.mysite.mongodbviewer-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.createProcessIdentifier(ObjectId.java:502)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:460)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterId.<init>(ClusterId.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:40)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:660)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:646)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:275)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:184)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:160)
    at it.mysite.mongodbmanager.data.MongoDBDriver.connect(MongoDBDriver.java:102)
    at it.mysite.mongodbmanager.fragments.MongoDBAccountDetailFragment.onClick(MongoDBAccountDetailFragment.java:101)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4780)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19865)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
... 22 more
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
09-11 19:13:50.901    7418-7418/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/cluster﹕ Cluster created with settings {hosts=[192.168.1.74:27017], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
09-11 19:13:50.918    7418-7418/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/System.out﹕ Connect to database successfully
09-11 19:13:50.924    7418-7418/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/cluster﹕ No server chosen by ReadPreferenceServerSelector{readPreference=primary} from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=UNKNOWN, connectionMode=SINGLE, all=[ServerDescription{address=192.168.1.74:27017, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING}]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
09-11 19:13:50.954    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient>
09-11 19:13:50.954    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient>
09-11 19:13:50.955    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient>
09-11 19:13:50.956    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/cluster﹕ Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 192.168.1.74:27017
com.mongodb.MongoException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:125)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient
at com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator.createSaslClient(ScramSha1Authenticator.java:61)
at com.mongodb.connection.SaslAuthenticator.authenticate(SaslAuthenticator.java:42)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultAuthenticator.authenticate(DefaultAuthenticator.java:32)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.authenticateAll(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:99)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:44)
at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:115)
at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
09-11 19:13:51.479    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient>
09-11 19:13:52.106    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient>
09-11 19:13:52.637    7418-7487/it.mysite.mongodbviewer I/art﹕ Rejecting re-init on previously-failed class java.lang.Class<com.mongodb.connection.ScramSha1Authenticator$ScramSha1SaslClient>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For anyone want to use `github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver` on Android, I have a solution!

I've forked from ufficial `github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver` and integrated classes from `github.com/koterpillar/android-sasl` to fix `javax.security.sasl` on Android.

Important: No driver-async is not ported because java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel doesn't exist on Android and doesn't exist any porting.

The result is a working synchronous MongoDB Android (Java) driver that you can download from https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver

**LAST UPDATE** (5 November 2015) : **3.2.0**-SNAPSHOT --> https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver/blob/gh-pages/JARs/mongo-java-driver-3.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?raw=true

Comment: Sasl.createSaslClient is returning null when I'm trying to use the plain authenticator, any ideas?

Comment: I'm sorry but I have not been able to manage this kind of authentication. I might have missed a particular implementation of library https://github.com/koterpillar/android-sasl . 
The problem could be:
```add
 java.security.Security.addProvider(new gnu.javax.crypto.jce.GnuSasl());
before SASL authentication methods will be active.```
I have to investigate about this possible oversight. Any idea / help is welcome ;)
Affected files are:
- GSSAPIAuthenticator.java
- PlainAuthenticator.java
- SaslAuthenticator.java (in authenticate and authenticateAsync methods)
- ScramSha1Authenticator.java

Comment: Yes I believe that was the problem. By the way I forked the official driver and did the same thing you did from the official branch 3.1.0, it is located https://github.com/grennis/mongo-java-driver

Comment: Does it work now with your forked version and MongoAndroid.init()?
I think that MongoAndroid.init() must be used from the driver and not from the client

Comment: It works but I dont know if the problem I had was originally was the missing addProvider call or not (that is all that MongoAndroid.init does)

Comment: Try to use your application without MongoAndroid.init() and test it ;)

Comment: I've have added the `java.security.Security.addProvider(new gnu.javax.crypto.jce.GnuSasl());` to SaslAuthenticator.java and recompiled the JAR. If you want @Greg, could you tell me if my version  work, please? In my old tests worked without that row.
You can download it from https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver/blob/gh-pages/JARs/mongo-java-driver-3.2.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?raw=true

Answer (score 7):

It looks to me like the ManagementFactory is a red herring, as the driver catches that exception and falls back to using a random number instead.

The real problem appears to be that the driver needs to authenticate with SCRAM-SHA-1, the implementation of which imports the following classes:

```
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import javax.security.sasl.SaslClient;
import javax.security.sasl.SaslException;
```

I suspect that these are not available in the Android platform, which is not a complete implementation of the Java Runtime Environment.

One thing you could try would be to run against MongoDB 2.6, against which the driver's authentication implementation only relies on java.security.MessageDigest.

Another thing to think about is putting a REST service between the mobile app and MongoDB that is responsible for proxying all interactions with the database.  The REST application can be run in an environment where the MongoDB driver will be fully functional.

Answer (score 2):

REST service workaround isn't the way, I must connect directly to mongodb instances.

**EDIT:**

Sync mongo-java-driver is correctly ported on Android with this porting: https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver

No driver-async is not ported because `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel` doesn't exist on Android and doesn't exist any porting.

If anyone has a solution to get driver-async working tell me please. The problem is in `java.nio.channels.AsynchronousSocketChannel` that not exist for Android

Comment: Please see: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/170463/why-to-use-web-services-instead-of-direct-access-to-a-relational-database-for-an as to why directly connecting to the DB is a bad pattern for Mobile apps.

Comment: I agree, but it is not my choice