# Android Studio: connecting to MongoDB server with Mongo Java Driver

Tags: java, android, mongodb

There's a lot of posts about this problem, but noone seems to work, so maby some things have changed.

I am trying to connect my android application to a MongoDB server located on mLab. I'm using Mongo Java Drived and have off course added the library to android studio.

It is possible to start the app, but when I click on the register button the application craches.

Here's my code:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import org.bson.Document;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoCollection;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final EditText username = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.username);
    final Button bRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bRegister);

    bRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String stringUsername = username.toString();
            try {
                addToDatabase(stringUsername);
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

private static void addToDatabase(String username){
    MongoClientURI uri  = new MongoClientURI("mongodb:///*mLab database URL */");
    MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri);
    MongoDatabase db = client.getDatabase(uri.getDatabase());
    MongoCollection<Document> coll = db.getCollection("newDB");

    Document doc = new Document("username", username);
    coll.insertOne(doc);
    client.close();
}
}
```

I also have permision.INTERNET in the manifest file.

Any help would be very appreciated!

//Edit
Stacktrace:

```
03/10 02:43:09: Launching app
Cold swapped changes.
$ adb shell am start -n "com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 4752 on device emulator-5554
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
W/org.bson.ObjectId: Failed to get process identifier from JMX, using random number instead
                     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
                         at org.bson.types.ObjectId.createProcessIdentifier(ObjectId.java:533)
                         at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:491)
                         at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterId.<init>(ClusterId.java:47)
                         at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:105)
                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:744)
                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:728)
                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:702)
                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:310)
                         at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:306)
                         at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:284)
                         at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity.addToDatabase(MainActivity.java:39)
                         at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:14)
                         at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
                         at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                         at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                      Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-support-annotations-25.1.0_11ac1b6ae4b8623fca16868c12f685674e962f99-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_9-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_8-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_7-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_6-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_4-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_3-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_2-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_1-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-slice_0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-mongodb-driver-core-3.4.2_cf1ecbf321a58b8bf97e118b2c0ff7614ac982a5-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-mongodb-driver-3.4.2_cfefe7ed281d321e57736b38e1e68fc6160680ac-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-vector-drawable-25.1.0_3dbe341ffa762dac2cc1137bc6aae1731f3bc1c0-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-v4-25.1.0_c534a46cb17b55c593319a94e0d90e0b75103a24-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-media-compat-25.1.0_b58e3876df91b49420cb0766dd6edfdbff0dedbc-classes.dex", dex file "/data/data/com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester/files/instant-run/dex/slice-com.android.support-support-fragment-25.1.0_d616629f11d994c207dfc4b5d01648e3194bccbc-classes.dex", dex f
I/cluster: Cluster created with settings {hosts=[ds123080.mlab.com:23080], mode=SINGLE, requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms', maxWaitQueueSize=500}
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: **FATAL EXCEPTION**: main
                  Process: com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester, PID: 4752
                  java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                      at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.<init>(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:41)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.create(DefaultClusterableServerFactory.java:68)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createServer(BaseCluster.java:360)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.SingleServerCluster.<init>(SingleServerCluster.java:54)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:114)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:744)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:728)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:702)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:310)
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:306)
                      at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:284)
                      at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity.addToDatabase(MainActivity.java:39)
                      at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:14)
                      at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29)
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637)
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.security.CodeSource java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource()' on a null object reference
                      at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.getDriverVersion(ClientMetadataHelper.java:111)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.getDriverInformation(ClientMetadataHelper.java:201)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.addDriverInformation(ClientMetadataHelper.java:182)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.ClientMetadataHelper.<clinit>(ClientMetadataHelper.java:64)
                      at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnectionFactory.<init>(InternalStreamConnectionFactory.java:41) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterableServerFactory.create(DefaultClusterableServerFactory.java:68) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.BaseCluster.createServer(BaseCluster.java:360) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.SingleServerCluster.<init>(SingleServerCluster.java:54) 
                      at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:114) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:744) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:728) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:702) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:310) 
                      at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:306) 
                      at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:284) 
                      at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity.addToDatabase(MainActivity.java:39) 
                      at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity.access$000(MainActivity.java:14) 
                      at com.newhdc.pedergb.mongodb_servertester.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:29) 
                      at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5637) 
                      at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22429) 
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776) 
Application terminated.
```

Comment: can you try printing client.toString() after MongoClient client = new MongoClient(uri); and see if you are able to make connection to the DB

Comment: The error seems to occur on line 39, which is the line where "new MongoClient(uri);" is made.

Comment: What error do you get ? Can you post the stacktrace ?

Comment: Thanks for the replies! Sorry for the long stacktrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. 
Indeed problem is that you call the connection in the main thread.
add the following to the onCreate method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9)
        {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the Mongo Java Driver does not work on Android, as Android is missing some Java classes, according to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32531278/464946). However, a kind StackOverflow user has forked the Mongo Java Driver and fixed the issue. You can see their version of the library on [Github](https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver).

Scroll down to the description and download the latest jar file. Right now, it's this one:

https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver/blob/gh-pages/JARs/mongo-java-driver-3.4.0-SNAPSHOT.jar?raw=true.

Next, go ahead and delete the line in your build.gradle dependencies for mongo-java-driver. The line to delete should look something like this:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:3.4.2'
    ...
}
```

Finally, add the jar you downloaded to your application ([guide here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16628496/464946)). Now your code should work without modification. I was able to use regular MongoDB functionality just fine, but I was not able to get GridFS to work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I actually did use the forked version that you are referencing though. I think my problem was that I ran the request in main thread. I haven't tried, but I'll guess it will work if I run it with AsyncTask or make a new thread.