# I try to calibration stereo camera using opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, calibration

I try to calibration stereo camera using opencv.

However, the screen does not appear normally.

.

I visited the corner using "findChessboardCorners".

The resulting coordinates were confirmed to be normal.

.

Output parameters via "stereoCalibrate" function,

Using the parameters, output to the screen.

However, it did not output normally.

what is the reason?

```
// call the function
FindChessboard(matImg1, matImg2, true);

const Size boardSize;
const Size2f squareSize;
vector<vector<Point2f>> imagePoints1, imagePoints2;
Size imageSize;
Mat map1, map2, map3, map4;

// Retrieves the corner
int FindChessboard (Mat view1, Mat view2, bool reg)
{
    if (view1.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    if (view2.empty()) {
        return 0;
    }

    assert (view1.size() == view2.size());
    imageSize = view1.size();

    Mat viewGray1, viewGray2;
    cvtColor (view1, viewGray1, CV_BGR2GRAY); 
    cvtColor (view2, viewGray2, CV_BGR2GRAY); 

    vector<Point2f> pointbuf1, pointbuf2;

    // Find the corner
    bool found1 = findChessboardCorners(view1, boardSize, pointbuf1,
        CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

    bool found2 =  findChessboardCorners(view2, boardSize, pointbuf2,
        CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH | CV_CALIB_CB_FAST_CHECK | CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

    // find
    if (found1 && found2) {
        // improve the found corners' coordinate accuracy
        cornerSubPix (viewGray1, pointbuf1, Size(11,11), Size(-1,-1), TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1 ));
        cornerSubPix (viewGray2, pointbuf2, Size(11,11), Size(-1,-1), TermCriteria( CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1 ));

        // push corner position
        if (reg) {
            imagePoints1.push_back (pointbuf1);
            imagePoints2.push_back (pointbuf2);
        }
        drawChessboardCorners (view1, boardSize, Mat(pointbuf1), found1);
        drawChessboardCorners (view2, boardSize, Mat(pointbuf2), found2);
    }

    return imagePoints1.size();
}
```

The above function is used to get the corner.

```
// start callibration
bool RunCalibration ()
{
    int size = imagePoints1.size();

    vector<vector<Point3f> > objectPoints;
    objectPoints.resize(size);

    // ..??
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < boardSize.height; j++)
            for (int k = 0; k < boardSize.width; k++)
                objectPoints[i].push_back(Point3f(k*squareSize.width, j*squareSize.height, 0));
    }


    objectPoints.resize(imagePoints1.size(), objectPoints[0]);

    //
    // 좌우 camera의 체스판 영상의 점들로부터 camera matrix, distortion coefficients와 R, P 행렬을 계산한다
    //

    Mat cameraMatrix1 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat cameraMatrix2 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
    Mat distCoeffs1   = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
    Mat distCoeffs2   = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
    Mat R, T, E, F;

    //cameraMatrix1 = initCameraMatrix2D(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imageSize, 0);
    //cameraMatrix2 = initCameraMatrix2D(objectPoints, imagePoints2, imageSize, 0);

    // start calibration
    double rms = stereoCalibrate(objectPoints, imagePoints1, imagePoints2,
        cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1,
        cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2,
        imageSize, R, T, E, F,
        CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO +
        CALIB_ZERO_TANGENT_DIST +
        CALIB_USE_INTRINSIC_GUESS +
        CALIB_SAME_FOCAL_LENGTH +
        CALIB_RATIONAL_MODEL +
        CALIB_FIX_K3 + CALIB_FIX_K4 + CALIB_FIX_K5,
        TermCriteria(TermCriteria::COUNT + TermCriteria::EPS, 100, 1e-5));

    bool ok = checkRange(cameraMatrix1) && checkRange(distCoeffs1) && checkRange(cameraMatrix2) && checkRange(distCoeffs2);
    if (ok) {
        Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
        Rect validRoi1, validRoi2;


        stereoRectify (cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2,
            imageSize, R, T, R1, R2, P1, P2, Q, CALIB_ZERO_DISPARITY, 1, imageSize, &validRoi1, &validRoi2);

        // save intrinsic parameters
        FileStorage fs("D:\\Sources\\trunk\\Sources\\Stereo_Scopic\\intrinsics.yml", CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
        if (!fs.isOpened()) return false;

        fs << "M1" << cameraMatrix1;
        fs << "D1" << distCoeffs1;
        fs << "M2" << cameraMatrix2;
        fs << "D2" << distCoeffs2;
        fs.release();

        fs.open("D:\\Sources\\trunk\\Sources\\Stereo_Scopic\\extrinsics.yml", CV_STORAGE_WRITE);
        if (!fs.isOpened()) return false;

        fs << "R" << R;
        fs << "T" << T;
        fs << "R1" << R1;
        fs << "R2" << R2;
        fs << "P1" << P1;
        fs << "P2" << P2;
        fs << "Q" << Q;
        fs << "imageSize" << imageSize;
        fs.release();

        initUndistortRectifyMap (cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map1, map2);
        initUndistortRectifyMap (cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2, imageSize, CV_16SC2, map3, map4);
    }

    return ok;
}


// show
int distortionCorrection(Mat leftImg, Mat rightImg) {
    float scale = 1.f;
    Mat img1 = leftImg.clone();
    Mat img2 = rightImg.clone();

    Size img_size = img1.size();

    string intrinsic_filename = "D:\\Sources\\trunk\\Sources\\Stereo_Scopic\\intrinsics.yml";
    string extrinsic_filename = "D:\\Sources\\trunk\\Sources\\Stereo_Scopic\\extrinsics.yml";
    Mat Q;
    Rect roi1, roi2;

    // load parameters
    if (!intrinsic_filename.empty())
    {
        // reading intrinsic parameters
        Mat cameraMatrix1 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
        Mat cameraMatrix2 = Mat::eye(3, 3, CV_64F);
        Mat distCoeffs1 = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);
        Mat distCoeffs2 = Mat::zeros(8, 1, CV_64F);

        FileStorage fs("D:\\Sources\\trunk\\Sources\\Stereo_Scopic\\intrinsics.yml", CV_STORAGE_READ);
        if (!fs.isOpened()) return false;

        fs["M1"] >> cameraMatrix1;
        fs["D1"] >> distCoeffs1;
        fs["M2"] >> cameraMatrix2;
        fs["D2"] >> distCoeffs2;

        //read extrinsic parameters
        Mat R, T;
        Mat R1, R2, P1, P2, Q;
        Rect validRoi1, validRoi2;

        fs.open("D:\\Sources\\trunk\\Sources\\Stereo_Scopic\\extrinsics.yml", CV_STORAGE_READ);
        if (!fs.isOpened()) return false;

        fs["R"] >> R;
        fs["T"] >> T;
        fs["R1"] >> R1;
        fs["P1"] >> P1;
        fs["R2"] >> R2;
        fs["P2"] >> P2;
        fs["Q"] >> Q;
        FileNode is = fs["imageSize"];
        img_size.width = is[0];
        img_size.height = is[1];

        Mat map11, map12, map21, map22;

        initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix1, distCoeffs1, R1, P1, img_size, CV_16SC2, map11, map12);
        initUndistortRectifyMap(cameraMatrix2, distCoeffs2, R2, P2, img_size, CV_16SC2, map21, map22);

        Mat img1r, img2r;
        remap(img1, img1r, map11, map12, INTER_LINEAR);
        remap(img2, img2r, map21, map22, INTER_LINEAR);

        img1 = img1r;
        img2 = img2r;


        namedWindow("img1m", 1);
        imshow("img1m", img1);
        namedWindow("img2m", 1);
        imshow("img2m", img2);

        waitKey(10);

        //stereo(img1, img2);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: So before you go any further, take a step backwards and realize that what you are attempting is inherently wrong. Mobile "client" devices have no business connecting to a database. That responsibility belongs to a different layer of API which you "app" talks to, where that in turn is the other part that actually talks to a database.

Comment: mongodb supports the java driver.
However, there is an error in newer versions.
The other version you customize is in use by many people.
However, errors only appear on special devices.
This article asks that. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42708540/android-studio-connecting-to-mongodb-server-with-mongo-java-driver

Comment: Unless you are developing a "database administration tool" that requires a direct connection, then *"these are not the droids you are looking for"*. It's simply something you do not do. Supported or not. Use a RESTful or other type of API as an "intermediary" instead. Stack Overflow uses a database, but my "browser" does not connect to it. Neither should your phone.