# Android Java API 21 to Azure MongoDB

Tags: java, android, mongodb, azure

Am trying to put a document on my MongoDB located in Azure. The problem I am facing is that I can't connect to the service. Azure provides the connector string so it should be working.

I am getting this errors

```
03-29 15:47:24.265 3578-3578/name.bagi.levente.pedometer W/org.bson.ObjectId: Failed to get process identifier from JMX, using random number instead                                                                      
        java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory"
```

and

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main                                                                           Process: name.bagi.levente.pedometer, PID: 3578                                                                           java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.security.CodeSource java.security.ProtectionDomain.getCodeSource()' on a null object reference
```

I am using this code to connect

```
//Line below causes exception
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI("AzureProvidedString?ssl=true&sslInvalidHostNameAllowed=true")); 
        BasicDBObject document = new BasicDBObject();
        document.put("id",2);
        document.put("location", 3);
        document.put("steps", 4);
        mongoClient.getDatabase("FitnessData").getCollection("FitnessCollection").insertOne(Document.parse(document.toJson()));
```

My dependencies

```
dependencies{
        compile group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.8.0'
        // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver
        compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongo-java-driver', version: '3.4.2'

    }
```

I tried using Mongo driver 3.2.2 and am getting a different error. Other solutions here seem to be the same and are working.

Comment: Is this MongoDB in a VM? Or is it DocumentDB with MongoDB compatibility enabled? If the latter: Does the collection already exist? Or are you assuming your insert will implicitly create the collection?

Comment: Its MongoDb on actual Azure cloud. There is only one option for MongoDb on Azure. I run the code on physical phone as well. I created database and collection in the Azure Portal manually, the purpose of the device is to send data only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to access MongoDB on Azure from Android using Mongo Driver for Java. There was a similar SO thread [mongodb 3.x driver Android compatibility](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529484/mongodb-3-x-driver-android-compatibility) which got a same issue with yours. The issue reason is the offical driver `mongo-java-driver` which is incompatible on Android. A solution is using the third-party driver porting for Android https://github.com/matfur92/mongo-java-driver.

However, directly access MongoDB on Android is not a good choice, even for sending data. Per my experience, the best practice is use REST webservice for sending & storing data on MongoDB, please refer to the MongoDB reference [`HTTP Interface`](https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) to get fully featured RESTful Web Services powered by MongoDB on Azure WebApps, or just create Azure Mobile App to receive data from Android.