# Android studio trying to connect to mongodb using AsyncTask throwing an error exception

Tags: android, mongodb, android-asynctask

```
MongoCredential credential = MongoCredential.createCredential(user, database, password);
MongoClientOptions options = MongoClientOptions.builder().sslEnabled(true).build();
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("localhost", 27017), Arrays.asList(credential), options);
```

throwing the following error

```
Failed to get process identifier from JMX, using random number instead
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/lang/management/ManagementFactory;
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.createProcessIdentifier(ObjectId.java:506)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:464)
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterId.<init>(ClusterId.java:47)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:69)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:683)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:669)
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:282)
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:187)
    at com.example.michael.version_10.Connection.doInBackground(Connection.java:40)
    at com.example.michael.version_10.Connection.doInBackground(Connection.java:30)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.michael.version_10-1/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.createProcessIdentifier(ObjectId.java:506) 
    at org.bson.types.ObjectId.<clinit>(ObjectId.java:464) 
    at com.mongodb.connection.ClusterId.<init>(ClusterId.java:47) 
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultClusterFactory.create(DefaultClusterFactory.java:69) 
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:683) 
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.createCluster(Mongo.java:669) 
    at com.mongodb.Mongo.<init>(Mongo.java:282) 
    at com.mongodb.MongoClient.<init>(MongoClient.java:187) 
    at com.example.michael.version_10.Connection.doInBackground(Connection.java:40) 
    at com.example.michael.version_10.Connection.doInBackground(Connection.java:30) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 
    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Comment: Take a look at this solution
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32776998/2993388)

Comment: I have forked as in the example above but my main issue seems to come from:  Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.lang.management.ManagementFactory" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/     Which i have tried to soleve with no avail.

Comment: are you see this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529484/mongodb-3-x-driver-android-compatibility

Comment: @MohamedElgarnaoui I have tried that solution but still doesn't work same problem

Comment: I was actually doing it the wrong way. It is not advisable to connect to MongoDB directly it is recommended to use an API. And that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I was actually doing it the wrong way. It is not advisable to connect to MongoDB directly it is recommended to use an Rest API. And that solved my problem.