# I want to use Mongodb for android application in linux platform

Tags: android, mongodb, relational-database, database

I am new to android. I want to develop weather application.In this i want to use mongodb to store the weather details upto one year.
Is it possible to do. can you please help me.

Comment: https://www.mongodb.com/presentations/mobilize-your-mongodb-developing-iphone-and-android-apps-cloud-0

Comment: "Is it possible to do" yes.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a mongo port for Android. I heard only one no-sql db for Android, that is realm.

But you can connect mongo through a webservice and use it in your android project.

Comment: Thanks Jason Bourne. you said we need to write webservice. can we write webservive in either PHP or J2EE .

Comment: Yes, webservice can be written in python, spring java , or php . @Madhu

Comment: http://www.codejava.net/java-se/jdbc/java-connecting-to-mongodb-database-examples

http://www.journaldev.com/4011/mongodb-java-servlet-web-application-example-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has downloads for several operating systems. However, Android is not one of those systems.

People use MongoDB as a "web service" for storing data, but it does not have any features to support multi-master replication or your occasionally connected mobile scenario.

If you need these types of features, you'll want to check out [CouchDB](http://couchdb.apache.org/) which specifically targets this scenario with [Android Couchbase](https://github.com/couchbase/Android-Couchbase).

Source : [MongoDB on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887887/mongodb-on-android)

Comment: If it gives worth answer to your question , then please accept it.Thanks