# MongoDB in Android Application

Tags: android, mongodb

Can a MongoDB be locally stored in an android phone and be connected to the app ?
When I searched over internet , It all bring backs results showing how to use  REST APIs to connect android apps to MongoDB servers

Comment: Android specific, though.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887887/mongodb-on-android

Comment: In case you don't find an answer, look for SQLite.