# use pre-built mongodb backend in android

Tags: android, mongodb

I'm learning basics of  "mongodb" on terminal..but I do not have knowledge how to make & use mongodb database in an android app .
Is there any tutorial for android app development with "mongodb"? I'm confused from 2 days how I start this? **:(**

Comment: I suggest that you find and read tutorials on MongoDB and come back when you have more specific questions.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/6887887/1440565

Comment: ok..but is there any online tutorial for mongodb in android ?

Comment: yes. That is what google is for.

Comment: i also don't find any website that have tutorial for this.. same problem .

Comment: @Code-Apprentice can you suggest any plateform for it? :)

Comment: @ShivamSharma what search phrase did you use?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice  tutorial for android mongodb.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is there any tutorial to learn android mongodb?

Comment: @ShivamSharma I suggest leaving out the word "for"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144130/discussion-between-shivam-sharma-and-code-apprentice).

Comment: @ShivamSharma There is nothing to chat about. Google can answer your question.