# Can i install mongodb on android and sync with mongodb on my server

Tags: android, mongodb, offlineapps

I want to develop a offline android app with mongodb as my database.

Following are the things i need to implement:-

1)Can i install mongo db on android device

If we can do point 1 following are the things I need additional to it

2)When the internet is available the data on the android device should go to the mongodb on my server.

So, I will have to instance of mongodb database one on the android device and one on the server.

When internet connection is not available all the data goes to android device mongodb.

When internet connection is available then the android device data will be synced to server mongodb database.Similarly any changes in server data base should reflect in android local database once we get internet connection.

Will mongodb support this kind of architecture.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887887/mongodb-on-android

Comment: You can use default database Sqlite. there is Realm too, unless you have any specific needs that only mongoDB can satisfy.

Answer (score 0):

You can not install mongodb in Android device, so, game over.

Comment: So any other recommendations for offline apps with above mentioned features

Comment: Use SQLite as local db in android and write code to sync it with remote MongoDB server. It's not a trivial task anyway.

Comment: Thanks Oscar will try it

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to install MongoDB locally on Android device, because MongoDB latest releases doesn't support android device's CPU architecture. But i read an article online i gave it a try and it finally worked i was able to use MongoDB on my android device, hope it'll work for you too just give it a try

Here is the link to the article: https://codipher.com/install-mongodb-on-android/