# Can i run zenbot on android?

Tags: android, mongodb, zenbot

Is it possibile to run zenbot on android?
I tested termux and Dory node.js

```
./zenbot.sh trade --paper
WARNING: MongoDB Connection Error:  MongoServerSelectionError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
    at Timeout._onTimeout (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/node_modules/mongodb/lib/core/sdam/topology.js:430:30)
    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:549:17)
    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:492:7) {
  reason: TopologyDescription {
    type: 'Single',
    setName: null,
    maxSetVersion: null,
    maxElectionId: null,
    servers: Map(1) { 'localhost:27017' => [ServerDescription] },
    stale: false,
    compatible: true,
    compatibilityError: null,
    logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes: null,
    heartbeatFrequencyMS: 10000,
    localThresholdMS: 15,
    commonWireVersion: null
  }
}
WARNING: without MongoDB some features (such as backfilling/simulation) may be disabled.
Attempted authentication string: mongodb://localhost:27017/zenbot4?
/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/lib/services/collection-service.js:18
      return conf.db.mongo.collection('sessions')
                     ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'mongo' of undefined
    at Object.getSessions (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/lib/services/collection-service.js:18:22)
    at Command.<anonymous> (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/commands/trade.js:450:48)
    at Command.listener [as _actionHandler] (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:413:31)
    at Command._parseCommand (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:914:14)
    at Command._dispatchSubcommand (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:865:18)
    at Command._parseCommand (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:882:12)
    at Command.parse (/data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/node_modules/commander/index.js:717:10)
    at /data/data/com.termux/files/home/zenbot/zenbot.js:46:13
    at FSReqCallback.oncomplete (fs.js:163:23)
```

That's the error when i try run the zenbot in termux

Can i fix this somehow???

Comment: The error message is telling you that the database call is incorrect, there is no "mongo" property.  Doublecheck the db structure, to find the correct name to replace  "conf.db.mongo.collection"

Comment: if so, it won't be easy... perhaps useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/q/6887887/2351568